# Enterprise Search site SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

I am using Enterprise search in  SP 2010 and 2013

In home page  I can find the search tabs like all sites , people in SP 2010. In SharePoint 2013 , I find only the Search box !!!

Where I can add search tabs in home page as SP 2010?

What's the difference between Tabs in search page list and tabs in Search results list in site contents

Please help me

Comment: Are you asking about Search navigation,  https://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/gg576964.aspx?

Comment: Couldn't clearly understand your question. can you please provide screenshots and elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you created a Basic Search Center in 2013. You should use the Enterprise Search Center for SharePoint 2013. It contains the "tabs" (we call them verticals). The difference is that they don't use the two lists that 2010 used. They use "Search Navigation" and a Search Navigation web part.